# Exclude page navigation from SP Search

Tags: search, current-navigation

I have a SharePoint publishing site with a site navigation common to all the pages.

When I crawl the pages, the SP Search indexes even the navigation content. So, if I search a word that is in the navigation section, the search returns all the pages containing that navigation.

How can I index all the page excluding the common navigation?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, to exclude it from SharePoint 2010 Search.

1. SharePoint 2010’s iFilter excludes content inside of a  tag. Note that each div nested in that one is
   re-evaluated for the noindex class, so nested divs may not work as
   you expect. The product team is considering changing this so that
   all nested divs are excluded.

Read More here about the examples.

[How to: Exclude part of a page from being indexed by SharePoint Search](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2011/01/26/how-to-exclude-part-of-a-page-from-being-indexed-by-sharepoint-search.aspx)

[Sharepoint 2010 exclude navigation from search](http://nvprakash.blogspot.com/2012/02/sharepoint-2010-exclude-navigation-from.html)

2. Another way to make a change to registry along with a piece of code.

   public class NavigationControlBase : UserControl

   ```
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Sends server control content to a provided <see cref="T:System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter"/> object, which writes the content to be rendered on the client.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="T:System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter"/> object that receives the server control content.</param>
       protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       {
           // Fix to remove the header text from search engines results
           var myBrowserCaps = Request.Browser;
           if (!myBrowserCaps.Crawler)
           {
               base.Render(writer);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

then edit the registry followed by IISreset.

[Sharepoint 2010 exclude navigation from search](http://nvprakash.blogspot.com/2012/02/sharepoint-2010-exclude-navigation-from.html)